# Navigation does not float correctly

Tags: html, css, position

I am experimenting with a navigation bar, and I am unsure of how to float part of the list to the right, without the text becoming laterally inverted. I want the first link to be on the very left side, whilst all the rest of the links are on the right side. Also, using float: right makes the list items very compressed, and I was wondering on how to get past this? I have chosen to do it this way so that I could use a line when hovering over the links. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQjozy

html:

```
<div class="navigationbar">
    <ul>

    <li class="one"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="two rightside"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li class="three rightside"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   <li class="four rightside"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="five rightside"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li class="six rightside"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
      <hr />
    </ul>
  </div>
```

css:

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;
  padding: .15rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 16%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 32%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 48%;
}

.five:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 64%;
}
.six:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 80%;
}
hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 16%;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.navigationbar{
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul{
  margin:0.7vh 0vh 0.7vh 0vh;
}
/*
.rightside{
  float:right
}*/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is closer to what you want I hope. 
Also using border bottom is much better way to handle a link underline. It will always line itself up under the content perfectly. I would also suggest changing the font size from vw to px or em and use media queries to change the font as the browser width gets smaller/larger.

EDIT: This is how I would correct your code but I don't think this is the correct way to accomplish this.

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .15rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding:6px 15px; /*add more spacing to links*/
}
li:hover {
  border-bottom:3px solid blue;
}

.navigationbar{
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul{
  margin:0.7vh 0vh 0.7vh 0vh;
}

.leftside {
  float:left;
}

.right_side_container{
  float:right
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="one leftside"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <div class="right_side_container">
        <li class="two"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li class="five"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li class="six"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
     </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want! However, with the hover, I want the line underneath to follow the cursor underneath, which was the purpose of the <hr>. Any ideas of how to do this? (Refer back to the first codepen). Thank you bro

Comment: I think that would involve javascript and tracking the mouse position and applying a position to the hr element based on the mouse. So if the width of the header was 400px and the mouse was found at 200px you would say `position absolute and left:50% (minus half width of hr)`  something like that.

Comment: Can you assign this as correct if it has helped you fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set a certain `width` to each of the links you floated to the right,that way it wont be compressed